# Content-Disposition inline does not work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, http-headers

I have a simple asp net core endpoint which return email file:

```
        [HttpGet("files/{id:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFileAsync(int id)
        {
            ...
            var fileName = $"{id}.msg";
            var filePath = ...;
            System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                Inline = true,
            };
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            return PhysicalFile(filePath, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(filePath));
        }
```

I want that browser tries to open file and it works in Firefox. But Chrome only downloads file even with `inline` `Content-Disposition`:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=10979.msg
Content-Length: 112128
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can I do "files/../../../../passwd"? does it work?

Comment: Maybe %2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to fix this?

**Firefox** help user to open file with a dialog but **Edge** and **Chrome** doesn't.
But you could choose the **"Always open files of this type"** option as below to open files automatically.

[image]

### Operation in Firefox, Edge and Chrome browser

### [image]

How to Undo "always open files of this type"?

- **Chrome**

[image]

- **Edge**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `Content-Type` to `application/msg`